# how do I query from parent model a array of other model in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have two Schema for user & todo. Every todo has an owner as a user, every user has an array of todos.

```js
// user.js
const TodoSchema = require('./todo').TodoSchema;

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 name: {
  type: String,
  required: true
 },
 todos: {
  type: [TodoSchema]
 }
});

module.exports.UserSchema = UserSchema;
module.exports.UserModel = mongoose.model('UserModel', UserSchema);


// todo.js
var TodoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 body: {
  type: String, required: true
 },
 owner: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'UserModel',
  required: true
 }
});

module.exports.TodoSchema = TodoSchema;
module.exports.TodoModel = mongoose.model('TodoModel', TodoSchema);
```

I entered data like this.

```js
var nUser = new UserModel({
  name: "Alex
)};

nUser.save().then(user => {
  var t = new TodoModel({
    body: "my new todo",
    owner: user._id
  });
  t.save().then();
});
```

But the problem is I want to get all the todos from a specific user, something like this...What is the correct way?

```js
UserModel.findOne({name: "Alex"})
.then(user => {
  // user.todos
});
```

P.S.
I can do this like TodoModel.find({owner: specific_user._id}), but I want it from UserModel.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for the proper way of doing it, I am gonna start with your User Schema. If you want to find all the todos of a user, then putting the todo documents inside an array in the User document is not required. So you should probably remove that from your schema.

After that you can use a simple aggregation to get your desired outcome.

```
UserModel.aggregate([
    {
      $match:{
        name:"Alex"
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup:{
        from:"todomodels",
        localField:"$_id",
        foreignField:"$owner",
        as:"todos"
      }
    }
  ])
```

this will return all the todos for that user in an array of the same name.